Iterate over DOM after Thenable Promise
Question one; I want to iterate over the DOM after a Promise, where I fetch a HTML fragment and insert it into the DOM asynchronously. When I use this.parse(), The iteration loop doesn't seem to log the inserted HTML fragments individually, but it does show the other DOM elements such as its parents, but not its children. I need to access each DOM element individually.
Question two; Even stranger, when I do this.parse instead of this.parse() it does log all the elements, including all fragments as separate DOM elements, which I want. But if I do this.parse, I cannot use "this" to access other functions inside the class otherwise I get a TypeError.
How is this possible, and what would be the solution?
Test.js
class test {
  anotherFunc(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }

  parse() {
    // iterate over all DOM elements.
    const docElements = document.all;
    for (let i = 0; i < docElements.length; i++) {
      console.log(docElements[i]);
      // I need this: this.anotherFunc(docElements[i]);
    }
  }

  page() {
    const promise = fetch('test.txt')
      .then((file) => file.text())
      .then((response) => document.getElementById('test').setHTMLUnsafe(response))
      .then(this.parse());
  }
}

const app = new test();
app.page();

Test.txt
<h1>Test</h1>
<h2>Test</h2>

Index.html
<div id="test"></div>

<script src="test.js"></script>

Expected outcome would be where I am able to iterate over each element in the DOM and be able to call other class functions.

Your call to this.parse() has to be inside an anonymous function, like with your other .then() callbacks.

Did you mean to do this?: .then(() => this.parse())

You are correct, such a small mistake! .then(response => this.parse()) works. Thank you!

There's no need for response there. setHTMLUnsafe() doesn't return the response, and you're not using it. Just use () => like David said.

The comments are correct, it's an early invocation of the parse method, which is a common mistake. Take the mock example below. It mocks the fetch to return a fake file after 1000ms and adds logs to your first 2 then methods. When you run this, you can see the order of the function calls is...
page
parse
// waits 1000ms
first then
second then

So you know that parse should be called last, after all the previous then.


const mockFetch = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve({ text: () => 'some text' }), 1000) // wait 1 second
})

class test {
  parse() {
    console.log('parse');
  }

  page() {
    console.log('page');
    const promise = mockFetch()
      .then((file) => {
        console.log('first then')
        return file.text()
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('second then')
        // return document.getElementById('test').setHTMLUnsafe(response)
      })
      .then(this.parse());
  }
}

let app = new test();
app.page();



So the solution is simply remove the invokation of parse and just pass the method.


const mockFetch = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve({ text: () => 'some text' }), 1000) // wait 1 second
})

class test {
  parse() {
    console.log('parse');
  }

  page() {
    console.log('page');
    const promise = mockFetch()
      .then((file) => {
        console.log('first then')
        return file.text()
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('second then')
        // return document.getElementById('test').setHTMLUnsafe(response)
      })
      .then(this.parse);
//     - or use anonymous function, especially when passing parameters
//    .then(() => this.parse());
  }
}

let app = new test();
app.page();



page
// waits 1000ms
first then
second then
parse


That made sense, thank you for your elaborate answer.
